# Mostrar JSON anidado JS Vue.js API Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, vue.js

Hice un API en node.js donde recibo estos datos, son la misma persona pero habla dos idiomas quisiera mostrarlo de la segunda forma que reconozca que es la misma persona por id y que muestre en un json anidado los datos del idioma

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "cedula": "123",
        "Nombre": "Andres",
        "IdiomaNativo": 1,
        "NivelDominio": 100,
        "idiomaNombre": "español",
        "Siglas": "esp"
    },
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "cedula": "123",
        "Nombre": "Andres",
        "IdiomaNativo": 1,
        "NivelDominio": 100,
        "idiomaNombre": "ingles",
        "Siglas": "eng"
    }
]
```

como los quiero mostrar

```
[
   {
        "Id": 1,
        "cedula": "123",
        "Nombre": "Andres",
   }
   "Idiomas":
     [
       {
         "IdiomaNativo": 1,
        "NivelDominio": 100,
        "idiomaNombre": "español",
        "Siglas": "esp"
       },
       {
         "IdiomaNativo": 1,
        "NivelDominio": 100,
        "idiomaNombre": "español",
        "Siglas": "esp"
       }

     ]

]
```

el frontend es con Vue.js no logro que se me muestre de la forma que quiero
en Vue.js lo manejo con axios el response

```
export default {
  el: "myFormPerson",
  data() {
    return {
      results:[],
    }
  },
  methods: {
     submitForm() {
         axios.get('http://localhost:8080/person/' + this.cedula)
        .then((response) => {
          this.results = response.data;
         //console.log(this.results);
         })
        .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        })
        .finally(function () {
        });
        //console.log(this.cedula);
     }, 
    }
}
```

Como se ve: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezHgH.png

Answer (score 0):

en el foro de ingles me respondieron, esta es la solucion

```
        this.info = Object.values(this.results.reduce((acc,{Id, cedula, titulo, Nombre, SegundoNombre, Apellido, SegundoApellido, sufijo,  IdiomaNativo, NivelDominio, idiomaNombre, Siglas}) => 
        (acc[Id]||={Id, cedula, titulo, Nombre, SegundoNombre,  Apellido, SegundoApellido, sufijo, Idiomas:[]}, acc[Id].Idiomas.push({IdiomaNativo, NivelDominio, idiomaNombre, Siglas}), acc), {}));

        console.log(this.info);

{
"Nombre:" Andres 
"Edad:" 
"Cedula:" 
"Idiomas:"
[
{
"Nombre:"español
"Sigla:" esp
"Idioma Nativo:" Si
"Porcentaje de dominio:" 100%
}
]
}
"Nombre:"ingles
"Sigla:" eng
"Idioma Nativo:" Si
"Porcentaje de dominio:" 100%
}
]
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).